# What caused these massive spikes in malware sites detected by Google in July 2012 and January-February 2014?

Tags: malware, detection

Google's [Transparency Report](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/overview) shows pretty huge spikes in malware sites detected by crawlers in July 2012 and in January/February 2014. I can't find any record of what these spikes were caused by however. Is there any publicly available information regarding what caused them?

Comment: Two guesses: [An exploit or exploits](https://www.exploit-db.com/webapps/?order_by=date_published&order=desc&pg=100) for infecting websites was published in June 2012 and was fixed at the end of July (possibly concernig Wordpress/Joomla). Google's crawlers scanned other segments of the net that were heavily infected.